# Good . amr editor for Android (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, audio

My requirements are unusual and hence hoping for solutions here

I listen to a lot of `. amr` talks which are typically 3 hours duration with a file size of around 20 Mb

I want to edit portions (i.e, cut, copy and save ) for memorising.  These segments are unpredictable in occurrence, hence, would *prefer* be able to edit *on-the-fly* (without nothing down the start and end timings). In the worst case,  am OK with noting down the timings and editing but the bigger problem is below

There are tons of apps that can do this but all of them fail, since they cannot handle such large duration files being more in line with ring tone makers from a small track.  They fail in either loading or editing or inconsistent performance. Listing them  is pointless since I have tried practically all the top reviewed ones over last 5 years

Doing it on a lap top is easy but is not an option. `. amr` format is ideal for sharing and storage so that is also a fixed parameter for input but since the recorded snippets would be short, recording in other formats is fine (Edited, since there don't seem to be strictly amr options)

Cost is not a constraint but if I need to pay would also like to be able to reduce noise, selectively Amplify, like one can do in desktop using `audacity` software.  Few paid apps offer such features but don't accept `. amr` input.  (Recording is non-professional and the venue far from ideal)

I searched alternate sources like Aptoide   F-Droid without success (
admittedly,  not a deep search)

I may have well missed an app that can do this and hoping one of you can point that out

Comment: I've got a small [list of audio editors](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_audioedit) – but for one I haven't tried any myself, and for two I'm afraid nothing new in there for you. Still, who knows – so I thought I mention it ;)

Comment: Thanks @Izzy...will try and if it works will ping you to convert into an answer

Comment: I've just added a few candidates. E.g. *Audio Clipper* mentioned something about "large files" with its last update.

Comment: Was afraid so. Sad, but was worth a try – sorry there's nothing better in my collection (if you find something, let me know to add it :).

Comment: Sure @izzy will update